# What are dyld_shared_cache_xxx files and how do I extract object files from them?

Tags: dynamic-linking, ios

I have a `dyld_shared_cache_armv7` file and I'm assuming that they hold various object files for a specific architecture. How do I extract the object files from it?

Comment: What does `file dyld_shared_cache_armv7 ` say (run it on an OSX or Linux machine)?

Comment: @Gilles Of course they wouldn't run. it's a different architecture. btw `nm` doesn't return any symbols, and `lipo` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Run the [`file` command](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/file.1.html). If it shows just “data”, also try on a Linux or Cygwin installation.